# Configure Spring Security OAuth2 TokenStore to use primary data source

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot project with 2 data sources configuration. Github [example](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/context/ContextProductionDatasource.java).

in my case I use OAuth2 authentication for security. I want to store user tokens into database.

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new  JdbcTokenStore();
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class JDBCTokenConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String dbDriverClassName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUsername;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource());
    }
}
```

The issue is that this will open a new connection to the database. I would like to use the existing datasource. Is this possible to implement this?

Comment: Then, instead of create a new datasource, why don't you inject the existing one included on your GitHub page?

Comment: Can you show me how please? I tried this: `@Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }` it's working with the primary datasource but I would like to have the control which datasource to be used.

Comment: Then what is the problem? As you mention in your question, you want to use the `primary datasource` and you achieve that injecting it.

Comment: But what if I want to use the second datasource?

Comment: How do you know which one to use? At this point, you have several options: 
**1.** Take a look to the internal code of `spring-oauth2` to know which class/classes manage `TokenStore` bean to know how to work with more than one. 
**2.** Change the scope of `tokenStore` bean creation to `Prototype` if you can know at "that moment" which datasource you want to use.

Comment: **3.** Store security information in only one datasource. **4.** Create different security microservices, every one with its own datasource. **5.** Create an unique security microservice multi-datasource. You can see an example in https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/tree/multi-datasource-security/security-jwt-service but it quite complex to follow